# Div not resizing even with clear or overflow

Tags: html, css, css-float, overflow

I have 2 boxes (About Us and Contact Us) that don't change (stack) when you resize the browser.  I've checked the forums and it looks like I need either a clear:both or overflow:hidden.  My problem is, I've tried both of those anywhere I can think of and nothing happens.

So far, I've tried overflow in the wrapper, box1 and box2.  As well as paragraphs 1-3.  I've also tried clear in pretty much every spot around/in/under the wrapper div in my HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the browser reaches the 768px breakpoint, you need to change the div's display mode to block so that it doesn't allow any other item in its horizontal space.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #box1 {
    display: block;
    width: 60%; /* Set according to your requirement */
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Stacked boxes]

[**JSbin**](http://jsbin.com/dupajalifo/edit?html,css,console,output)

Comment: That fix takes the Contact Us and puts it under the About Us no matter the browser sizing.  ie.  When browser is full size the Contact Us should be to the right of the About box.  With the suggested fix, it drops it under About.

Does that make sense?  I just need the Contact box to move on page resize, but when full page it should be floated over to the right side of the other box.

Comment: It works fine here: http://prntscr.com/7qybff I added the @media rule just for that. You forgot to add that?

Comment: Hmm...you're right.  It works fine in JS, but not in real life.  I checked in FF and in Chrome.  Here's the link to the test site:

http://test.completesources.com/fitnesspro

Comment: That is because you have to put the media query style after the default style. Change the order of it. Also if it didn't work. Give it a width of 50% on the default style.

Comment: Done.  Thanks Manoj.  Sorry, I didn't understand how that worked.  It's perfect now.  Many thanks!